# c2011 error c++ when trying to do polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm trying to achieve polymorphism with my image manipulation program. I keep getting this error, I think it is caused from me defining `scale` twice in both the header file and the cpp file.

```
Error   C2011   'scale': 'class' type redefinition
```

and I am not sure what to do. Thanks for any help.

.cpp file

```
   Image *begin= new Image(750, 750);
   begin->read("picture1.jpg");
   Image *enlarged= new Image(1500, 1500);

    scale *pass= new scale(*imgScale);
    pass->manipulator(1500, 1500);

    pass->load("manipulated.jpg");

    class scale : public Image
    {
    public:    
        scale(Image const &firstimg)
        {
             w = firstimg.w;
             h = firstimg.h;
            pixels = firstimg.pixels;
        }

        void manipulator(int w2, int h2)
        {
            Image *temp = new Image(w2, h2);
            float x_ratio = (float )w / w2;
            float y_ratio = (float )h / h2;
            float px, py;
            for (int i = 0; i < h2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < w2; j++)
                {
                    px = floor(j*x_ratio);
                    py = floor(i*y_ratio);
                    temp->pixels[(i*w2) + j] = this->pixels[(int)((py*w) + px)];
                }
            }
        }    
};
```

header file

```
#pragma once    
#ifndef manipulator_H
#define manipulator_H

class scale : public Image
{
    public:
        scale(Image const &firstimg);

        void manipulator(int w2, int h2);
};
#endif
```

Comment: Don't declare the class in the cpp file. You do that only in the header. The compiler is correct you should not redefine the class..

Comment: Also what is all the code above the class in the cpp file? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: When you write code, start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time. That way, you could have discovered -- and dealt with -- this bug when the code was a fiftieth of its current size.

Comment: And didn't we see almost the same code from a different user a few hours ago.. Although that was different error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring you class Scale in two different files, in the algo header file and in the .cpp file. Actually, I don't know why are how using inheritance if you are creating a new Image in your zoom function.

Your header, scale.h should be something like that:

```
#pragma once    
#ifndef ALGORITHMS_H
#define ALGORITHMS_H

class Image;    
class Scale {
    public:
        explicit Scale(Image const &beginImg);
        void zoom(int w2, int h2);

    private:
    // Here all your private variables
    int w;
    int h;
    ¿? pixels;
};
#endif
```

And your cpp file, scale.cpp:

```
#include "scale.h"
#include "image.h"
Scale::Scale(Image const &beginImg) : 
        w(beginImg.w),
        h(beginImg.h),
        pixels(beginImg.pixels) {}

void Scale::zoom(int w2, int h2){
       Image *temp = new Image(w2, h2);
       double x_ratio = (double)w / w2;
       double y_ratio = (double)h / h2;
       double px, py;
       // rest of your code;
}
```

And, then in the place you want to use this class, example your main:

```
int main() {
    Image *imgScale = new Image(750, 750);
    imgScale->readPPM("Images/Zoom/zIMG_1.ppm");

    Scale *test = new Scale(*imgScale);
    test->zoom(1500, 1500);

    test->writePPM("Scale_x2.ppm");

    delete imgScale;
    delete test;
    return 0;
}
```

In any case, consider using smart pointers instead of raw pointers and take a look in to the different modifications I did.